# Contact form 7 submit without completing all required fields

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Using wordpress contact form 7 plugin to do a questionaire. I have 2 buttons **continue** and **done** - if you click **continue** it should send only first inputs and skip the hidden ones. On continue it will show the hidden fields and than the form must check all required fields.

Let me show you the exact code:

```
<div class="first">
    <input type="text" id="one" required>
    <input type="text" id="two" required>
    <input type="text" id="three">
</div>
<button id="continue" value="continue"> or <button id="done" value="done">

<div class="second" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" id="four" required>
    <input type="text" id="five" required>
    <input type="text" id="six">
    <button id="send" value="send">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#continue').click(function(){
        $('.second').show();
        $('#continue, #done').remove();
    });
    $('#done').click(function(){
        $('.second ').remove();
        // submit without div.second fields
    });
    $('#send').click(function(){
        // submit all div.first / div.second fields
    });
});
</script>
```

Now if i click **done** the form is asking me to complete all fiels, even the hidden ones. Tried to remove them before submit, still asking...

Comment: Have you tried removing the `required` html attribute?

Comment: Also, use visibility: hidden;, not display: none;

Comment: tried to remove **required** and more attributes, same thing.. using `display:none` only in this example..

Answer (score 0):

Give a Try to this,

```
$('#formName').validate({
    ignore: "#hiddenInputId"
});
```

OR,

You can disable the configuration validator by adding:

```
define( 'WPCF7_VALIDATE_CONFIGURATION', false );
```

to your wp-config.php, or adding:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_configuration', '__return_false' );
```